# adding new permanent column to data frame python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am currently building a fake dataset to play with. I have one dataset, called patient_data that has the patient's info:

```
patient_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5),columns='id name dob sex state'.split())
```

This gives me a sample of 100 observations, with variables like name, birthday, etc.

Clearly, some of these (like name sex and state) are categorical variables, and makes no sense to have random numbers attached to it.

So for "sex" column, I created a function that will turn every random number <0 to read "male" and everything else to read "female." I would like to create a new variable called "gender" and store this inside this variable:

```
def malefemale(x):  
if x < 0:
    print('male')
else:
    print('female')
```

And then I wrote a code to apply this function into the data frame to officially create a new variable "gender."

```
patient_data.assign(gender = patient_data['sex'].apply(malefemale))
```

But when I type "patient_data" in the jupiter notebook, I do not see the data frame updated to include this new variable. Seems like nothing was done.

Does anybody know what I can do to permanently add this new gender variable into my patient_data dataframe, with the function properly working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need assign back and for new values use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
patient_data = patient_data.assign(gender=np.where(patient_data['sex']<0, 'male', 'female'))
print(patient_data.head(10))

         id      name       dob       sex     state  gender
0  0.588686  1.333191  2.559850  0.034903  0.232650  female
1  1.606597  0.168722  0.275342 -0.630618 -1.394375    male
2  0.912688 -1.273570  1.140656 -0.788166  0.265234    male
3 -0.372272  1.174600  0.300846  1.959095 -1.083678  female
4  0.413863  0.047342  0.279944  1.595921  0.585318  female
5 -1.147525  0.533511 -0.415619 -0.473355  1.045857    male
6 -0.602340 -0.379730  0.032407  0.946186  0.581590  female
7 -0.234415 -0.272176 -1.160130 -0.759835 -0.654381    male
8 -0.149291  1.986763 -0.675469 -0.295829 -2.052398    male
9  0.600571 -1.577449 -0.906590  1.042335 -2.104928  female
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your custom function as

```
def malefemale(x):  
   if x < 0:
     return "Male"
   else:
     return "female"
```

then simply apply the custom function

```
patient_data['gender'] = patient_data['sex'].apply(malefemale)
```